# Executing a batch file from Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, batch-file, console

I have written a small batch file that copies an exe from solution to the `system32` folder.

```
copy "blah.exe" "%systemroot%/System32"
```

The batch file works fine and copies the exe if ran from the desktop by double clikcing (placed exe on the desktop as well)

However, I tried doing that from Windows Application by:

```
Process.Start("sample.bat");
```

(EXE file and batfile -> Properties -> Output to Copy Always)
The cmd window does come up, but the .exe file is not there in the destination directory. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you expect `blah.exe` to be in the output folder?

Comment: Messing around with system32 is a bad idea... the more recent windows version have several security measures (among other UAC) to protect against this... what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: @Yahia: Trying to copy a sysinternal utility to System32 to be abel to access it from command line

Comment: @user1240679 the correct way to do this is NOT to put it into system32 BUT to add the relevant path to `PATH` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your batch file change path to that particular folder where you have blah.exe, change to the particular drive and then to particular folderlets say your source folder is C:\test then type cd\test in the batch file, it should be something like:

```
C:
cd\test
copy "blah.exe" "%systemroot%/System32"
```

or use copy with complete path e.g

```
copy "C:\test\blah.exe" "%systemroot%/System32"
```

EDIT: 
To copy using CMD try:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new       System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C copy /b blah.exe %systemroot%/System32";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Edit 2: Or for batch file

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/c sample.bat");
```

Comment: I have the exe and the batch file in the same folder. I tried this on putting both `batch` file and `exe` on desktop, and just executing the above batch file, which works fine. In this case, I did not need to change the source directory to `cd Users/someuser/Desktop`. Putting the full path on batch file here can work, but when I would deploy the project, the path for this `cd` in batch file would change, in which case nothing would happen.

Comment: If I run the batch file directly from the bin/debug output folder, it still works adn the exe gets copied to `System32`. It's just that this is not running from `Process.Start`

Comment: @user1240679, just check the edited answer, also check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/c-sharp-run-command-prompt-commands

Comment: @habis.osu: I am still wondering why is that the problem with batch file, rather than passing arguments.

Comment: @user1240679 you could specify batch file in process.start like System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/c mybatch.bat"); but you have to start process against cmd